# django ORM - order by status value

Tags: django

I have a model with three statuses: `draft`, `launching`, `launched`. What I want is to display models in a particular order: first drafts, then launching ones, and then launched ones. I don't want to name my attributes as `0_draft`, `1_launching`, `2_launched` as this will be a problem down the road; i need clear values in my DB.

Is there a way to annotate these values with some integers?

The ideal syntax for this would look like this:

```
def detect_status_number(campaign):
    if campaign.status == 'draft':
        return 1
    ... etc ...

cs = Campaign.objects.annotate(new_arg=lambda campaign: detect_status_number(campaign))
cs = cs.order_by('new_arg').all()
```

this obviously doesn't work; but is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
cs = Campaign.objects.extra(
select={"weight_status":"case when campaign.status='draft' then 0 when campain.status = 'launching' then 1 else 2 end"}
).order_by('weight_status')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you could certainly make your approach work, let me recommend another approach: using the choices field and "enumeration". Here is an example:

```
STATUS_TYPE = (
    (1, "draft"),
    (2, "launching"),
    (3, "launched"),
)
```

And then for your model field:

```
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_TYPE)
```

I realize that this may not be an acceptable answer if your model design is already set, but this is a good design pattern to know.